# DT_USED entry in .dynamic section of ELF file

Tags: c, elf, binutils

I am curious about DT_USED entry in .dynamic section. However, I could only find two code examples that describe this entry.

1.

```c
#define DT_USED     0x7ffffffe  /* ignored - same as needed */
```

in https://github.com/switchbrew/switch-tools/blob/master/src/elf_common.h

2.

```c
    case DT_USED:
    case DT_INIT_ARRAY:
    case DT_FINI_ARRAY:
      if (do_dynamic)
        {
          if (entry->d_tag == DT_USED
          && VALID_DYNAMIC_NAME (entry->d_un.d_val))
        {
          char *name = GET_DYNAMIC_NAME (entry->d_un.d_val);

          if (*name)
            {
              printf (_("Not needed object: [%s]\n"), name);
              break;
            }
        }

          print_vma (entry->d_un.d_val, PREFIX_HEX);
          putchar ('\n');
        }
      break;
```

in http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/binutils/binutils/readelf.c

I want to know, what's the meaning of "Not needed object"? Does it mean that file names listed here are not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when looking at Solaris dynamic linker features, it is possible to find more information in the public Illumos sources (which were once derived from OpenSolaris).  In this case, it seems that `DT_USED` is always treated like `DT_NEEDED`, so they are the essentially same thing.  One of the header files, [`usr/src/uts/common/sys/link.h`](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/4e0c5eff9af325c80994e9527b7cb8b3a1ffd1d4/usr/src/uts/common/sys/link.h#L243) also contains this:

```
/*
 * DT_* entries between DT_HIPROC and DT_LOPROC are reserved for processor
 * specific semantics.
 *
 * DT_* encoding rules apply to all tag values larger than DT_LOPROC.
 */
#define DT_LOPROC   0x70000000  /* processor specific range */
#define DT_AUXILIARY    0x7ffffffd  /* shared library auxiliary name */
#define DT_USED     0x7ffffffe  /* ignored - same as needed */
#define DT_FILTER   0x7fffffff  /* shared library filter name */
#define DT_HIPROC   0x7fffffff
```

There may have been planned something here, but it doesn't seem to be implemented (or it used to be and no longer is).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful